# Powershell Objects Sorting On Property - Descending - Not working

Tags: powershell, sorting, psobject

I am sorting the contents of the a text file as below

```
APPLE|FINAL|20220122065900|0
APPLLE|PRE|20220122061500|0
MANGO|PRE|20220126113400|0
MANGO|PRE|20220125102200|0
MANGO|ASSYN|20220125102200|0
```

```
$file = Get-Content D:\FOXXXX\DOWNTIME\POWER\test.txt
Foreach($line in  $file)
{
     New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "t1" = $line.split("|")[0]
        "t2" = $line.split("|")[1]
 } | Sort-Object -Property t1 -Descending |Select-Object t1, t2

}
```

I am getting the following output with no sorting. Please let me know what I am doing wrong

```
t1     t2   
--     --   
APPLE  FINAL
APPLLE PRE  
MANGO  PRE  
MANGO  PRE  
MANGO  ASSYN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sorting each element of the collection instead of sorting all the collection, in other words, `Sort-Object` should be outside the loop:

```
$collection = Foreach($line in $file)
{
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "t1" = $line.split("|")[0]
        "t2" = $line.split("|")[1]
    }
}

$collection | Sort-Object -Property t1 -Descending
```

On the other hand, your text file is *pipe delimited*, you can use `ConvertFrom-Csv` or `Import-Csv` (if from a file) to convert it into an object:

```
@'
APPLE|FINAL|20220122065900|0
APPLLE|PRE|20220122061500|0
MANGO|PRE|20220126113400|0
MANGO|PRE|20220125102200|0
MANGO|ASSYN|20220125102200|0
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Header T1, T2 |
Sort-Object T1 -Descending
```